# Ruby showing in $PATH for WSL2, but not available to run

Tags: environment-variables, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm running WSL2.  If I `echo $PATH` in the WSL2 terminal, I see

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:
/mnt/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:
/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:
/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:
/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:
/mnt/c/Strawberry/c/bin:/mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/site/bin:
/mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin:
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Calibre2/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:
/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
/mnt/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2/:
/mnt/c/Ruby27-x64/bin:/mnt/c/Ruby27-x64/bin:
/mnt/c/Users/cmari/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:
/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4/bin:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe:/mnt/c/Users/cmari/Downloads/python-3.8.2:
/mnt/c/Users/cmari/Downloads/lxml-4.5.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl:
/mnt/c/Users/cmari/Downloads/libxml2_python-2.9.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl:
/mnt/c/Users/cmari/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:
/mnt/c/Users/cmari/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/snap/bin
```

However, if I check `ruby -v` in my WSL2 terminal, it complains `Command ruby not found,` , even though in my regular Windows commandprompt, it obediently spits out the version number.  How do I help my WSL2 find Ruby?

Comment: So ruby is installed "on the windows side" ?  .. try ruby.exe -v .. also, your path is abhorrent.  You should clean that up.

Comment: [You need to install Ruby within your WSL instance instead of Windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405528/installing-ruby-2-3-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks, that shows my version :)  When I try `gem install dory` though, it complains `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory`... any suggestions?

Comment: You should look at @Ramhound suggestion.  As super cool as WSL is, the stuff on the linux side can't use the stuff on the windows side without tweaking.  Just install the ruby package on both sides and chances are that this will go away.